# Use local version of an included file in Helm chart

Tags: configmap, helm3

I have created a Helm chart and host it from my organization's private Helm repository. I intend this chart to be used by several different groups in my organization. The chart creates a ConfigMap like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
data:
  config.yaml: |-
{{ .Files.Get "config.yaml" | indent 4}}
```

The chart looks like:

```
mychart/
  Chart.yaml
  values.yaml
  config.yaml  ** The ConfigMap content **
  templates/
```

That is, the ConfigMap is a YAML file whose content is exactly the content of `content.yaml`.

The file `content.yaml` is provided by the chart and is contains several dozen lines. Users of this chart need to be able to substitute their *own* version of `config.yaml` for the one that comes with the chart.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can solve this by keeping it as a yaml file. We do something similar to your use case and we solved it by having the ConfigMap stored in a separate helm chart. Then, add that chart as a dependency on your Chart.yaml but don't use the URL in the definition:

```
dependencies:
  - name: my-config-map
    repository: "@artifactory"
```

Now, you can change the location of where to pull the ConfigMap charts by team. I.e. each team would define the repository location differently to pull a different chart:

```
helm repo add artifactory-dev https://artifactory.mycompany.com/artifactory/helm-dev-local
```

-vs-

```
helm repo add artifactory-dev https://artifactory.mycompany.com/artifactory/helm-qa-local
```